# Help with this rule

Tags: commerce, rules

How can I do this rule:

Before adding a product to the cart:

if there is a product in the cart with the same title name plus a character "-".
then
    set the price of the product with the name ending in "-" to 0 euros.

Answer (score 0):

If a customer adds "Y-" (costing $5) to the cart and then adds a "Y" (costing, say, $6) to the cart, then set the price of "Y-" to ($0).

You'll need to use the `Calculating the sell price of a product` event since that's actually what you're doing and you're actually calculating the sell price of the "Y-" product and not of the "Y" product. When dealing with Rules, it's important to make these distinctions.

Anyway, what you'll then need to do is create a few custom conditions (which you can do using rules). It's a bit long to review over here but the logic is roughly the same to the answer in this question: [Exclude Items from Flat Rate Shipping Calculation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183718/exclude-items-from-flat-rate-shipping-calculation/186172#186172).

The differences are that:

- Instead of testing for an amount, you're testing to see if a product is in the cart, so it's a boolean.
- You're not setting free shipping, you're setting the price of the product.
- You're comparing the title based on some arbitrary string (title + '-').

Comment: Thanks @nvahalik, let me try. What would be the comparison command to check if a product name with a "-" character is the same than the product without the "-"?. Is better use text comparison or data comparison?. How can I include a token for a field inside in a php evaluation box together with substr and strpost php command?. Could you give and example in rules UI of how to write this comparison please? I am trying hours and I don't get it.